# How to recover .profile on mac

Tags: macos, .profile

I have mis-configured ~/.profile while adding new enviroment variable now i want to restore my original .profile for my macOS, i am not mac expert please help me. 
None of my shell command is working for me like ls, java, php etc
Please help

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Restore from a backup.

Comment: how i will restore from backup i am new to mac please if you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "original" .profile on OS X (i.e. by default it doesn't exist).  If you don't have a backup, probably the easiest thing to do is rename the .profile so it doesn't cause trouble.  Then, if you want, you can try to figure out what's wrong with it, edit it to fix the problem, and reinstall it (you probably have a bad assignment to PATH, from what you describe).  To rename it, use:

```
/bin/mv ~/.profile profile-disabled.txt
```

(note that using `/bin/mv` instead of just `mv` will work even if your PATH is completely messed up.)